# How can we use Holo Theme(supported in android 4.x) in android 2.3

Tags: android, themes

Can any one tell how to use themes used in higher android version to lower android version.I referred this link 
http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html but does not seemed to be helpful and also searched everywhere but didn't find anything.Final option SO

Any help will be great.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: can you please post a link or guide for help if you found a resource for doing it?

Answer (score 2):

Holo is not in the lower versions of Android, so unsurprisingly, you can't use it in the old versions. I suppose technically you could try to style everything yourself the same way, maybe starting by copying the theme from the source code of ICS, but there's no automatic way. Maybe you can find someone who has already backported the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Some people are using this: https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere . It seems to work for a lot of people, but I havent got it to work yet, maybe its intellij idea playing tricks on me. It is however probably a better idea to style the components you need yourself, especially if you want it to blend in on diferent android versions.